# When i run the recycler view in android it was showing the following error how to get ride of this error?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

MyAdapter.java
    package com.example.askselva.recylerexample;

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
        private ItemClass[] itemsData;
        public MyAdapter(ItemClass[] itemsData) {
            this.itemsData = itemsData;
        }

        // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
        @Override
        public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                       int viewType) {
            // create a new view
            View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_layout, null);


            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
            return viewHolder;
        }

       @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

            // - get data from your itemsData at this position
            // - replace the contents of the view with that itemsData

            viewHolder.txtViewTitle.setText(itemsData[position].getTitle());
            viewHolder.imgViewIcon.setImageResource(itemsData[position].getImageUrl());


        }

        // inner class to hold a reference to each item of RecyclerView
        public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            public TextView txtViewTitle;
            public ImageView imgViewIcon;

            public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
                super(itemLayoutView);
                txtViewTitle = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
                imgViewIcon = (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
            }
        }
        // Return the size of your itemsData (invoked by the layout manager)
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return itemsData.length;
        }
    }
```

MainActivity.Java

package com.example.askselva.recylerexample;

```
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        ItemClass itemsData[] = {
                new ItemClass("Help",R.mipmap.help),
                new ItemClass("Delete",R.mipmap.content_discard),
                new ItemClass("Cloud",R.mipmap.collections_cloud),
                new ItemClass("Favorite",R.mipmap.rating_favorite),
                new ItemClass("Like",R.mipmap.rating_good),
                new ItemClass("Rating",R.mipmap.rating_important)};


        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        MyAdapter mAdapter = new MyAdapter(itemsData);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    }
}
```

ItemClass.java

```
public class ItemClass {

    private String title;
    private int imageUrl;

    public ItemClass(String title, int imageUrl) {

        this.title = title;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(int imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }
}
```

Error Log:

```
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.askselva.recylerexample, PID: 14350
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:631)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(Native Method)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.askselva.recylerexample.MyAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MyAdapter.java:25)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.askselva.recylerexample.MyAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MyAdapter.java:13)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5223)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4449)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4359)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1961)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1370)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1333)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:562)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2900)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3071)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14860)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14860)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14860)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:437)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14860)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14860)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14860)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14860)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2013)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1770)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1019)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5725)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-04 23:21:47.969 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample E/AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Lo
11-04 23:21:48.057 14350-14350/com.example.askselva.recylerexample I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 14350 SIG: 9
```

This is the Error i'm getting when i execute this program.Please spot me the error which i did in this code

Comment: As in log `InflateException: Binary XML file line #2` means problem is which xml files. please post xml files with question

Comment: Thank's I found Problem is in  xml file.. which i placed corder xml in layout in should be in drawable folder

Answer (score 0):

If you'll notice in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(int,%20android.view.ViewGroup)) the second parameter is for a `ViewGroup` which will be the parent of the generated View. You shouldn't give it null, but instead give it the parent passed into `onCreateViewHolder`:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_layout, parent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you wrote `<RecyclerView>` ?

This should be `<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>`

I hope this helps